# How to Customize netsuite task manager

Tags: netsuite

how to customize the task manager in netsuite which is using in a sales company
in netsuite task manage i can assign a task to any other employees 
but when i assign a task its showing to everyone else
i need to assign my task to a person and only he can view that task none other dont need to see the task
also i need to assign a task in the name of my department to another department 
actualy 
i need to assign a task to another one
(that is one to one assign)
i need to assign a task to a person in the name of my department
(Many to one)
and from my department to another department
(many to many)

Answer (score 1):

To answer one of the questions: "I need to assign my task to a person and only they can view that task." For this check [X] PRIVATE TASK in the Primary Information section.

[image]

Comment: Thank you brian for ur answer but,
i Need the entire task to be private by default